# Execute multiple http request - Parse Cloud Code

Tags: promise, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

i have an array of stores, where the address and some other things are stored.

Now I want to iterate through this array and geocode the lat / lng coords and save them to the database.

With the code below I get double or triple entries of the same store. Do I miss something with the scope here?

Thanks!

```js
var promises = [];

data.forEach(function (element, index) 
{
    var addressString = element.plz + " " + element.stadt + "," + element.adresse;
    var url = encodeURI("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
        addressString);
    var promise = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url:url
    }).then(function (http) //SUCCESS
        {
            var geocodedObject = new Parse.Object("GeocodedStores");
            geocodedObject.set("storeID", element.id);
            geocodedObject.set("Latitude", http.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
            geocodedObject.set("Longitude", http.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);

            return geocodedObject.save(null, {
                useMasterKey: true
            });
        },
        function (http, error) 
        {
            response.error(error);
        });
    promises.push(promise);
});

return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a working solution. It looked like it was a problem with the scope. I put the code in a seperate function and added this returned promise to an array.

```
var fn = function(element, geocodedObject)
{
    var addressString = element.plz + " " + element.stadt + "," + element.adresse;
    var url = encodeURI("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
        addressString);

    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: url
    }).then(function(http)
    {   

        geocodedObject.set("storeID", element.id);

        geocodedObject.set("Latitude", http.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
        geocodedObject.set("Longitude", http.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);

        geocodedObject.set("address", addressString);

        return geocodedObject.save(null, {
            useMasterKey: true
        });

    });
}

var promises = [];

for (var k = 0;k<data.length;k++) 
{
    var geocodedObject = new Parse.Object("GeocodedStores");
    promises.push(fn(data[k], geocodedObject));
}



Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function () {
    response.success("DONE");
});
```